# How backup works when flow.xml size more than max storage?

Tags: apache-nifi

i have check below properties used for the backup operations in Nifi-1.0.0 with respect to JIRA.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-2145

```
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.max.time=1 hours
nifi.flow.configuration.archive.max.storage=1 MB
```

Since we have two backup operations first one is **"conf/flow.xml.gz"** and **"conf/archive/flow.xml.gz"**

I have saved archive workflows(conf/archive/flow.xml.gz) as per hours in "max.time" property.

At particular time i have reached "1 MB"[set as size of default storage].

So it will delete  existing **conf/archive/flow.xml.gz** completely and doesn't write new flow files in **conf/archive/flow.xml.gz** due to size exceeds.

No logs has shows that new flow.xml.gz has higher size than specified storage.

**Why it could delete existing flows and doesn't write new flows due to storage?**

In this case in one backup operation has failed or not?

Comment: Have find out JIRA.
**https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-3373**

Comment: Voting to close as it is somewhat unclear what the question is, and it appears you already found the answer as well.